# How to populate the time zone in WPF?

Tags: wpf

Can anyone help me to populate the time zone in WPF? Should this be done as style or is there any other way?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the Time Zone?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f89248c2-e427-4333-9b7d-97f0fbd1ca65/getting-timezone-using-culture-or-region-info

Comment: Hi grantnz. in my app user can set time . based on Zone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this

```
TimeZone zone = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;
```

Comment: can you explain me bit more